# Delete all corresponding items from SQLite

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I have the following statement which get all the list item and then do loop to delete each item from the database.

Is there a better way to handle deleting all items?

**IRepository.cs**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : new()
{
    TableQuery<T> AsQueryable();
    T GetById(object id);
    List<T> GetWithChildren(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void CreateTable();
    void Clear();
}
```

**AnotherService.cs**

```
protected IRepository<TModel> Repository => _repository ?? (_repository = new Repository<TModel>(_factory));
```

**Service.cs**

```
private IRepository<Class> _classRepo;
public void DeleteClasses(string classId)
{
  foreach (var class in _classRepo.Get(x => x.ClassId.Equals(classId)).ToList())
  {
   _classRepo.Delete(class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Delete or DeleteAll method in the IRepository interface?

Comment: I have Delete method, but not DeleteAll

Comment: What does Clear() do?

Comment: Where is the "following statement"?

Comment: Change the words

Comment: You can implement a DeleteAll and then pass it a list of ID's to delete and delete them all in a single call to the database. Or if you always want to delete all the items, just implement a dedicated method for it that truncates the table.